# RacketGL Can't Load Any Procedures

Tags: windows, opengl, racket, nvidia

I've been trying to get OpenGL working with Racket, and I've managed to get a basic canvas working:

```
#lang racket/gui

(provide tennis-canvas%)

(require opengl)

(define tennis-canvas%
    (class* canvas% ()

        (inherit with-gl-context swap-gl-buffers)

        (define/public (gl-init)
            (with-gl-context
                (lambda ()
                    (print (glGetString GL_VERSION))
                    (glClearColor 1.0 0.0 1.0 1.0)
                )
            )
        )

        (define/override (on-paint)
            (with-gl-context
                (lambda ()
                    (glClear GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
                    (swap-gl-buffers)
                )
            )
        )

    (super-instantiate () (style '(gl no-autoclear)))
    )
)
```

With one caveat: if I use `(require opengl)` it does not work, and gives the error `OpenGL procedure not available: glGetString`. If I switch to `(require sgl/gl)` everything's fine, but as far as I can tell, `sgl/gl` is stuck on OpenGL 1.5, and I want to use the new stuff. From what I can find online, this is some kind of core/compatibility context issue, but I have really have no idea how to solve it. I've tried fiddling with the legacy option in `gl-config%` and it doesn't help anything.

I have an Nvidia GTX 750, and according to `GL_VERSION` I'm on OpenGL 4.5.

Comment: works fine on linux. Did you call?: raco pkg install opengl

Comment: I did install the package. I'm guessing this is a Windows-only issue. [This](https://github.com/ntoronto/pict3d/issues/9) appears to be a similar issue. The maintainer of library did some voodoo to fix it. I tried to steal their OpenGL bindings, but it didn't work.